# php pdo code to update all values in database

Tags: php, pdo

sir ,

I have two textbox in my form.

My data is like...

column1         price

501                1

502                2

503                3

504                1

505                2

506                3

507                1

like wise...

I need to **update all value of price column from inputed textbox value.**

**for Ex Inputted values in textbox like**

**monthtextbox = 1**

**pricetextbox = 50  then**

**update all 1 with 50 in price column.**

below is my code but this is not updating any values.plz suggest me an update statement.

```
<?php   
    $errors = array();      
    if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {       
                    $month = $_POST['month'];   
                    $price = $_POST['price'];
                    $modified = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
                    $updaterow = $database->updateRow("UPDATE scheme_master SET price = :price WHERE price = :price",
                     array(':price'=>$price,':price'=>$month,':modified'=>$modified));  
                     $_SESSION['message'] = "Data Updated Successfully";

    }                           
?>  


<form name="frm2" method="post" action="">
<div id="page-wrap">
<table height="50">
<tr>
<td width="8%">Enter Month :</td>
<td width="19%"><input type="text" name="month" class="" required = "" /></td>
<td width="11%">Enter Price :</td>
<td width="20%"><input type="text" name="price" class="" required = ""/></td>

<td width="12%" height="45"><input type="submit" name="update" value="Save"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Your query makes no sense. An array can only hold unique keys...

Comment: Also when using real prepared statements you cannot use the same named parameters either way.

Answer (score 0):

Change price column with month in where condition and also an array.
this will update all values and work for you.

```
<?php   
    $errors = array();      
    if(isset($_POST['update']))
    {       
                    $month = $_POST['month'];   
                    $price = $_POST['price'];                   
                    $updaterow = $database->updateRow("UPDATE scheme_master SET price = :price WHERE price = :month",
                     array(':price'=>$price,':month'=>$month)); 
                     $_SESSION['message'] = "Data Updated Successfully";

    }                           
?>
```